# Using System.Diagnostics.Debug In An ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

I'm trying to see the output of a foreach loop in my code in the output window in an ASP.NET web app, but I don't get any results even though there is valid data. I've done a fair amount searching using Google with this issue, but nothing I've done works. Here is the code in my ASPX page:

```
List<MyClass> myClasses = GetMyClasses();
foreach (MyClass myClass in myClasses)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(myClass.SomeProperty);
}
```

The code is very straight-forward. When I debug this page, myClass.SomeProperty has the value I want, but nothing is getting printed to the output window. What could I be missing? I cannot use a Response.Write because my Response stream is being used to create an Excel file. I also don't want to use Tracing.

### Update

I have this in my web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    ...
</system.web>
```

Comment: So what was the problem/How did you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry no full answer, but a bit long for a comment)

There are debug related features. (Related [What does the optimize switch do](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do.aspx))

- Generation of debug Symbols
- C# IL optimization
- Jitter Optimization
- The DEBUG conditional define.

What you need for your problem is the `DEBUG` conditional. I guess the `debug="true"` switch affects only the debug symbols but not the conditional.

---

edit:
hmm strange. scottgu states at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/06/429723.aspx that `debug="true"` should affect that conditional.

> Note that the value of debug in a web app is driven by the value of the  value in your web.config file.

Answer (score 1):

You are using System.Diagnostics.Trace, rather than the ASP.NET Tracing. To get System.Diagnostics.Trace working within ASP.NET see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0ectfxd(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0ectfxd%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I also had a same issue but later found out that  Debug.Writeline() didn't work with my unit tests.

Comment: This isn't for a unit test. This is for an ASP.NET web form page. I'm just trying to compare the output for a few foreach loops.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set

```
<system.web> <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" />  </system.web>
```

in your web.config?